# history.js Github like URL change - changing parts of url with slash

Tags: javascript, pushstate, history.js

I am working with History.js and have one problem: I want to change the parts of URL that are before slash, like github when browsing in directories( https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/ ).
My code now looks like this:

```
  History.pushState(null, "Program od: "+programBack, "program/"+day);
```

And when I push the button multiple times, the url changes to:
program/program/program/6-10-2011 because history.js only changes the part after /.

Is there any way to deal with this in History.js?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is how to get history.js to use absolute/full urls instead of relative urls, then change `"program/"+day` to `"/program/"+day`